# FB Graph API - cannot enter with my own App token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i facing an issue regarding the FaceBook Graph API.

actually a friend of me, have an FB App whitch can be used for the Graph API.
But in that case I activate a FB dev APP for myself, i'm not able to generate a valid security Token with the App-ID and App-Security.

At first the App is live and activated. For that I don't understand the error message at the end.

Second I don't want to have a User-Token with a validation for an hour.

These are the step's i following:

1. getting App Token

   `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? client_id=20179479xxxxxx&client_secret=3048xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials`

The result i'm receving:

```
"access_token": "20179479xxxxxxx|Pqxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
```

Now if im trying to use the Graph API Explorer and trying these token as authentication, I'm facing an #200 OAuthexception

my request:
    Get -> /v2.12/coca-cola

> "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/",

Have somebody any ideas how to solve or what i'm missing here?

With the Security Token from my friend he can use the example with coca-cola from the developer like in the documentation and example from FaceBook as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is changing the API due to a security [issue](https://www.marketingmag.com.au/news-c/news-zuckerberg-facebook-recovery-mode/). This means new apps have more restrictions and less access (for the minute) than apps that were already registered and using the API, probably why your friends key works. Seen as your app is either new or hasn't recently accessed the data you are requesting, you currently cannot fetch it.

Its not known what features will be removed from the API following this incident - as a result I wouldn't come to rely to heavily on any feature the API offers.

Im hearing that the ability to retrieve events could either be removed or the data you can access from an event is going to be severely limited, however thats not from any official facebook source. All apps will be subjected to a review according to this official facebook [post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/), before they are granted access to the Events API, Groups API, and Pages API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I created the app last Oktobre. But I already except that these could coming from the actual discussion.

Comment: Can somebody try if they can create and open it with the graph explorer? Maybe I made a mistake belong my handling with the api.

Comment: No worries - If you havent requested stuff recently then they could have suspended your key in light of this issue. I also have an old app and have been requesting data every day - now I also am returned a 200 response but there is no data attached to it, so it will just be due to changes to the API.

Comment: What i already Figured out is that you have the same authorization like before with a user token validation for an hour. For that reason I don't really know if I made a mistake with the app token or facebook restricted so much.